# Increment count if exist else push in array Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have this data I'm working with

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    tags: [
      {
        name: "red",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        name: "black",
        count: 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to update the count if **tag.name** exist else push the new tag object in **tags** array